# New Ubuntu install, only see's 1 core of my dual core CPU

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, virtualbox, cpu, multi-core

Brand new install of 11.10 64-bit Ubuntu.  While getting my conky script up and running I kept seeing the error `Conky: attempting to use more CPUs than you have!`  and that was weird because Ive never seen that before with other distros on the same box which is definitely a dual-core CPU.

Doing some investigating it seems that Ubuntu is only recognizing 1 core on the CPU.  I do have ACPI enabled in my BIOS.  Im not sure if it matters but this is a guest VM installed in VirtualBox on a Windows7 64-bit host.

Here is the output of: `lshw -class cpu`

```
*-cpu
   product: AMD Athlon(tm) 7850 Dual-Core Processor
   vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
   physical id: 2
   bus info: cpu@0
   width: 64 bits
   capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx fxsr_opt rdtscp x86-64 3dnowext 3dnow up rep_good nopl extd_apicid pni monitor lahf_lm cr8_legacy
```

Output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 16
model       : 2
model name  : AMD Athlon(tm) 7850 Dual-Core Processor
stepping    : 3
cpu MHz     : 2687.223
cache size  : 512 KB
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 5
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx fxsr_opt rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow up rep_good nopl extd_apicid pni monitor lahf_lm cr8_legacy
bogomips    : 5374.44
TLB size    : 1024 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Full output of `dmesg` can be found here http://pastebin.com/b03PetVx

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your VM has been configured to provide a single virtual core given that `dmesg` output.

The following documentation might help you in reconfiguring your VM to provide multiple cores:

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-processor